# How to parse values from a JSON field that is also a JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swifty-json

I have a JSON that has one field that in itself contains another JSON. I am having trouble parsing values from this embedded JSON. I am using SwiftyJSON and can extract the embedded JSON as JSON type (`swiftyJSON` type). But I am unable to do anything with it further to get values from the embedded JSON.

`thisjson[0]["MESSAGE_JSON_BODY"]` will return a JSON type.

`thisjson[0]["MESSAGE_JSON_BODY"].string` will convert this JSON to string.

Now I need help parsing fields from `MESSAGE_JSON_BODY` JSON. How to parse the fields in the embedded JSON?

Comment: I have corrected a few capitalization mistakes in the content and have highlighted inline code block. I have also removed the tool name from the title as it is not required due to the presence of tags.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to solve this problem myself, here I print out the field value for  "fieldkey":

```
            if let stringdata: String = thisjson[0]["MESSAGE_JSON_BODY"].string{
                var data: NSData = stringdata.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                let msgjson = JSON(data: data)
                println(msgjson["fieldkey"])
            }
```